# xss bypassing angle brackets and double quotes escaping

Tags: security, xss

Say I want to maliciously call a function which is already defined, myfunc().

How could I achieve xss attack bypassing double quote and angle brackets escaping?

```
<h2>Profile of INPUTNAME</h2><p>INPUT2</p><a href="INPUTURL">Homepage</a>
```

(The upper case fields are user inputs)
How could I call myfunc() without adding the script tags around it?

Answer (score 3):

(Un)fortunately it appears that XSS won't be possible in this instance.

If angle brackets and double quote characters are escaped, this is enough to prevent XSS in HTML body and double quoted entity value contexts.

Technically under the [XSS Experimental Minimal Encoding Rules](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Experimental_Minimal_Encoding_Rules) for HTML body, the `&` character should be encoded too, but I can't see a way here to use that to the attacker's advantage either in the HTML body or within the entity value.

The only exception to this is if the character set was specified as [UTF-7 (or as the attacker you could change it to such) then you could use the following attack](http://openmya.hacker.jp/hasegawa/security/utf7cs.html):

```
INPUTNAME = +ADw-script+AD4-myfunc()+ADw-/script+AD4-
```

this would be rendered as

```
<h2>Profile of <script>myfunc()</script></h2><p>INPUT2</p><a href="http://example.com">Homepage</a>
```

Comment: Does UTF-7 work in modern browsers? Setting it in the `<meta>` tag doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Yes, Internet Explorer still supports it (not Chrome or FF though). You may need to set the content type in a HTTP header rather than a meta tag.

Comment: If you dun escape `&`, attacker might encode the payload with unicode?

Answer (score 0):

You can try these injections

```
INPUTNAME=<img src=X onerror=myfunc>
INPUTURL="><img src=X onerror=myfunc>
```

which will try to call the myfunc javascript function since it will fail to load the image named X

Comment: I have tried that, but double quotes and angle brackets are encoded, and therefore cannot generate the valid html statement.

Comment: hmm then it will be all the more difficult but would try with null byte something like %00<img src=X onerror=myfiunc> ... It would work if you delegate validation or encoding to native calls like C . And if INPUTURL was unquoted we could tried many other things but since it is quoted we cannot inject JS calls .

Answer (score -3):

Try this injection: `<a href="javascript:myFunc();">`;
when someone clicks on the link, the code gets run.
If you want to pass string parameters, use slashes (like /string/ vs "string")